# Antd Forms: Set min value of field dynamically

Tags: forms, antd

I got a form using antd (5.x) forms. When a certain condition is met, I want to dynamically restrict the min value of a date field.

I know there are so-called FormInstance methods in antd. E.g. this one which sets the value of a field dynamically:

`form.setFieldValue('birth_date', '2020-01-01')`

Is there sth similar for setting the props of the form item dynamically? Something like `form.setPropValue('birth_date', {min: '2000-01-01'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example is from Ant Design **[official documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#components-date-picker-demo-date-range)**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <DatePicker
    defaultValue={dayjs('2019-09-03', dateFormat)}
    minDate={dayjs('2019-08-01', dateFormat)}
    maxDate={dayjs('2020-10-31', dateFormat)}
  />
);

export default App;
```

If we consider the code above, we could **store the minDate and or maxDate into its own useState** (*or even redux state*).

That way you **could dynamically control the date-range** from which the user can select the date.

**Note**, the  component can be integrated within the form so you can use that.

**Note**, this code is in TypeScript, in case you want it in JS, you can select from (II.) as shown in the img below.
[image]

Comment: PS, here is another Ant Design link, this one shows how you could add a <DatePicker> to your <Form> https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-variant

Comment: Thx, that nudged me into the right direction :)